# doThrow Exception not throwing for spring MVC unit test?

Tags: java, spring, exception, junit, mockito

ive tried switch to a when() and get compiler errors

i have successfully used doThrow(...) in another test in the same project, so i dont know whats going on here

Unit test code:

```
doThrow(new Exception("the client cancelled the request, ya dingus!")).when(handler).write(any());

MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post("/myPath")
            .content(String.valueOf(mockValidRequest))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .characterEncoding("utf-8"))
            .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())
            .andReturn();
```

Code I am testing (handler method for /myPath):

```
@PostMapping("/myPath")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleRequest(@RequestBody MyPojo request) {
 try {
        handler.write(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Exception thrown during event processing: " + e, HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
    }

return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

The problem is the test says the actual result is a 200 success, when there should have been an exception caught, and a service unavailable 5xx response.

Comment: Can you ensure that `write(...)` in your system under test is not called with `null`? `any()` will not match `null`. As an aside: you should type the `any()`-matcher, e.g. `any(Request.class)` (or whatever is applicable).

Comment: yeah i usually type matcher classes but was just trying to generalize the question and remove my POJO names ... but yeah, the "request" is not null when i debug, so its not being called with null (also not shown are null checks which prevent null from being passed to that write() method

Comment: @Turing85 lmk if you have any thoughts on the solution ... im wondering if theres some kink or limitation with MVC unit testing and spying on methods

Comment: Nope, sorry. I am blank. Would have to see the program for myself in a debugger.

Comment: @Turing85 i mean on the solution i posted below... calling the handler method directly versus using mockmvc

Comment: Oh. True that. I normally use `when(...).thenThrow(...)` (doesn't work on `void` method though). In this form, the whole call goes within the `when(...)`-parameter. But  with `doThrow(...).when(...)` the method call comes AFTER the `when(...)`.

Comment: @Turing85 figured it out ...was using the wrong annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the proper answer to my issue:

I didnt have this snippet in my original post, but the `handler` was being instantiated in the test like this:

```
@Mock
EventHandler handler;
```

it needed to be:

```
@MockBean 
EventHandler handler;
```

My guess is since `@MockBean` is the spring mock, and `@Mock` is from Mockito, it was probably mocking an event handler that was instantiated outside of the Spring container. Thus why I didnt think it was picking up the doThrow ... it did pick it up, but spied on the wrong instance.

Answer (score 1):

i found that i could get the tests to pass calling the function directly ... it just seems like MockMvc is not incorporating the doThrow logic

revised unit test:

```
doThrow(new Exception("some error")).when(handler).sendToSqsWriter(any());

ResponseEntity<String> response = controller.handleRequest(new Gson().fromJson(new JSONObject(mockApptRequestBody);.toString(), SeamAppointmentRequest.class));

assertTrue(response.toString().contains("some error"));
assertTrue(response.getStatusCodeValue() == 503);
```

all the json/gson jazz is resolving runtime parsing errors